# Loading PHPs via XMLHTTPRequest don't share the same variable scope

Tags: php, html, scope, xmlhttprequest, global-variables

I understand the concept of global variables in PHP and understand the pros/cons regarding the use of global variables. Nevertheless, I've decided to use them, but I'm running into issues regarding the scope and visibility of them.

Situation:

Depending on the selection of a menu I'm loading different PHPs into a div. The PHPs require the same common set of data, which I want to avoid to be reloaded and kept in memory all the time for each PHP. In the example below the `GlobalVars.php` will be kept in memory twice and will also fetch the data from the database twice.

The problem is, that by loading them into the div, they don't share the scope of the `main.html`. The global variables in `GlobalVars.php` can be seen and accessed by the code in `another.php`, but not in `PHP1.php`, nor in `PHP2.php`.

GlobalVars.php:

```
<?php
    $var1 = "*";
    $var2 = 5;
    // Various SQL fetches
?>
```

Main.html:

```
<?php require_once="./GlobalVars.php"; ?>
<?php require_once="./another.php"; ?>

<script>
    function LoadHTML(href) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return xmlhttp.responseText;   
    }

    switch(menuitem) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: document.getElementById("contentdiv").innerHTML=LoadHTML("./PHP1.php") break;
        case 2: document.getElementById("contentdiv").innerHTML=LoadHTML("./PHP2.php") break; break;
        case 3: break;
        default:
    }
</script>
```

PHP1.html:

```
<?php
    require_once="./GlobalVars.php";
    // code ...
?>
```

PHP2.html:

```
<?php
    require_once="./GlobalVars.php";
    // code ...
?>
```

The question is, how can I load the PHPs into a div and 'see' and work with the variables in the scope of `main.html`?

Regards

Carsten

Comment: It doesn't work because javascript is executed at the client side. and php is a serverside language. Also you could just require globalvars before you require php1 and php2 so you don't have to require globalvars again in those files.

Comment: @Sjoerd de Wit: Actually, I did require `GlobalVars.php` right at the start of `main.html`. But when it gets to the javascripts the PHP engine is done and the memory is being freed by GC. Starting another PHP with JS it will then allocate its own variable scope (heap) and not re-use the one from the PHP run before. The solution I described below works for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by not loading PHP1 and PHP2 through JS, but earlier in the PHP engine run. Instead of loading the PHPs into the same `DIV` I now load them into different `DIV`s. The visibility of those `DIV`s is then being controlled through JS later on.

The variable `$LastScreen` is being pulled from an SQL DB and contains the last screen shown, so that the user gets the same screen up that he had before he reloaded the page.

Generation of the `DIV`s:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="myclass" id="screen1"
            <?php if (strcmp($LastScreen, "screen1") !== 0) {echo " style=\"display:none; \"";} ?>
        >
            <?php require_once './PHP1.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="myclass" id="screen2"
            <?php if (strcmp($LastScreen, "screen2") !== 0) {echo " style=\"display:none; \"";} ?>
            >
            <?php require_once './PHP2.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Switching screens in JS:

```
<script>
    function SwitchScreen (screen){
        var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < arr.length;i++) {
            arr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        document.getElementById(screen).style.display = "inline";

        // push screen name to SQL
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

Regards

Carsten